# Find probability distribution - choosing points from a circle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, circles

From a disk R we choose a point. Let X denote distance between chosen point and circle's centre. Find distribution of a variable $X^2$. I have no idea what should i do about that whatsoever so i would appreciate detailed explanation.

Comment: I do not understand your notation. I would really appreciate more detailed answers.

Comment: Assuming you mean a disk rather than (the edge of) a circle, what is the probability that $X \le a$ for some $0 \le a \le R$?  What is the probability that $X^2 \le b$ for some $0 \le b \le R^2$?  What is the corresponding density?

Comment: Do you know about integration in polar coordinates?

Comment: I do but this should be solvable without polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint/Outline:

1. You mean to say pick a point randomly (uniformly) inside the circle. Then $X$ represents the distance from the origin to that point. I would approach this using the cdf, meaning compute $P(X<x)$.
2. Once you have found the distribution of $X$, use your preferred method to find the distribution of $Y=X^2$.

It might help to draw some pictures.

Comment: could than the cdf be $\frac{t^2}{R^2}$ for $t\in[0,R]$?

Comment: Yes. Take the derivative to get the density of $X$. The density of $X^2$ should be $\frac{1}{R^2}.$

Comment: for $t>R$ cdf is one and for everything bellow zero is zero? and that is the whole answer?

Comment: No, what you have is the "whole" distribution for $X$. Remember that the question is asking for the distribution for $X^2$.

Comment: What to do with this than? To find distribution for the desired variable? Will it be $1/R^2$?

Comment: Yes. I wrote to "use your preferred method". I usually use a change of variable $f_Y(y) = f_X(\sqrt y)/\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|.$

Answer (score 0):

The point $P$ is chosen uniformly in the disk with centre $O$. Thus the area of the disk with centre $O$, and going through $P$, is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,\pi R^2]$. But this area is $\pi X^2$, so $X^2$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,R^2]$.